# Spring Data Solr

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, solr

I am new to spring framework previously I have worked with solr using solrj. But now in my case I want to use spring data solr in spring mvc . From where can I get the detailed steps for configurations. I found some related stuff [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-configuration/), still I am not clear.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring guys tend to document their products very well and in public. So you can find their [official documentation about Spring Data Solr](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/).

This covers currently as of version 1

1. an introductory part about Spring Data Repositories in general and a
2. a reference guide [how Solr can be used in conjunction with Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/solr.repositories.html)
3. additional features of the Solr integration

So I would recommend you to read the whole thing, as you say you are new to Spring and to Spring Data.

The page http://spring.io maybe a good starting point for you in general, when you want to dive into the Spring ecosystem. Especially the [docs](http://spring.io/docs) and [guides](http://spring.io/guides) section there.

Answer (score 0):

Apart above mentioned links, I found [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-solr-tutorial/) tutorial very nice which tells you all the steps to get going with spring-data-solr.

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-solr-tutorial/